Invisible Obstacle / pre-drawn obstacle
snippet of the map
I'm making a Pokemon game in Processing Java for a school assignment, and I need to make it so that the wooden stumps are obstacles for the movement system.
Since these are pre-drawn into the background, how would I be able to do this?
The only method I've been able to think of is to make invisible rectangles that would be obstable, or to make a grid that the character can move in, and exclude those rectangles from the grid.
However, I'm unsure as to how to do either of these, or whether or not they would work.

Your idea is basically good. Whenever your player wish to move, before it can move have a method validating for everything that may prevent that move, like "is there an obstacle on the target coordinate", "is there a NPC on that coordinate", etc etc. If the method returns True, your character may move, else it cannot move in that direction.

Also yes, if those obstacles are pre-drawn you'll have to enter coordinates somewhere anyway. It may be easier to avoid pre-drawn backgrounds and create a class for map objects which will determine how they affect the player movements (block him, slow or accelerate him, make water noise while he moves, etc). Then you let the algorithm "draw" the map and manage the collisions accordingly.

for the first idea; how would you check whether or not there is an entity on the target coordinate?

Please read [ask] and how to provide a [mcve]. Also, helpful to read How do I ask and answer homework questions?

I made you a short example so you can experiment with it. It's not exactly how I would have made this, but I suspect that you are trying to learn and I didn't want to swamp you with techniques a bit more advanced than what you probably use right now.
For this example, I decided on a 10x10 tiles map, where every tile is 60 pixels wide.
I use a couple global variables to keep track of coordinates:
int tileSize = 60;
float[][] obstacles;
int pcX, pcY;

Now in the setup() method I fill in some of these coordinates: the player and the obstacles starting coordinates:
void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  
   // initializing the obstacles array
  obstacles = new float[10][2]; // 10 entries with 2 numbers each
  // the numbers are xy coordinates
  // first obstacle is at 0,0
  // second is at 0, 1, etc
  obstacles[0][0] = 0;
  obstacles[0][1] = 0;
  obstacles[1][0] = 0;
  obstacles[1][1] = 1;
  obstacles[2][0] = 0;
  obstacles[2][1] = 2;
  obstacles[3][0] = 0;
  obstacles[3][1] = 3;
  obstacles[4][0] = 4;
  obstacles[4][1] = 4;
  obstacles[5][0] = 4;
  obstacles[5][1] = 5;
  obstacles[6][0] = 4;
  obstacles[6][1] = 6;
  obstacles[7][0] = 4;
  obstacles[7][1] = 7;
  obstacles[8][0] = 0;
  obstacles[8][1] = 8;
  obstacles[9][0] = 0;
  obstacles[9][1] = 9;
  // etc. for every obstacle there is on your map
  // i did move some around just to demonstrate the principle, but yours are all in the same column
  
  // here I set up starting coordinates for the player character
  pcX = 6;
  pcY = 4;
}

I make sure to catch the player's inputs with the keyboard (I'm using WASD because it's easy):
void keyPressed() {
  println(pcY);
  if (key == 'd') { move(1,0); }
  if (key == 'a') { move(-1,0); }
  if (key == 's') { move(0,1); }
  if (key == 'w') { move(0,-1); }
}

The move method will validate if the player has the right to move before I update his coordinates:
void move(int xx, int yy) {
  // if the player character cannot do that move, this method will return before the pc's coordinates are updated
  
  // validate if the player character is going to go out of the map (I made the map 10 tiles x 10 tiles)
  if (pcX + xx < 0 || pcX + xx > 9) { return; } 
  if (pcY + yy < 0 || pcY + yy > 9) { return; }
  
  // validate if the player character is going to walk over an obstacle
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<obstacles.length; i++) {
    if (pcX + xx == obstacles[i][0] && pcY + yy == obstacles[i][1]) { return; } 
  }
  
  // as there was nothing forbidding the move, the pc's coordinates can now be updated
  pcX += xx;
  pcY += yy;
}

Finally I can make a game loop that lets you test this code:
void draw() {
  background(255);
  drawBackground();
  drawPC();
}

As I don't want to use images in my example, everything will be drawn as a rectangle!:
void drawBackground() {
  int i;
  fill(200, 0, 0);
  
  // here I draw red squares on tiles that are obstacles. If your background isn't already drawn you don't have to do that part
  for (i=0; i<obstacles.length; i++) {
    rect(tileSize*obstacles[i][0], tileSize*obstacles[i][1], tileSize, tileSize);
  }
}

void drawPC() {
  fill(0, 200, 0);
  rect(tileSize*pcX, tileSize*pcY, tileSize, tileSize);
}

Here you go, here's the entire code for an easier copy-and-paste experience:
int tileSize = 60;
float[][] obstacles;
int pcX, pcY;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  
   // initializing the obstacles array
  obstacles = new float[10][2]; // 10 entries with 2 numbers each
  // the numbers are xy coordinates
  // first obstacle is at 0,0
  // second is at 0, 1, etc
  obstacles[0][0] = 0;
  obstacles[0][1] = 0;
  obstacles[1][0] = 0;
  obstacles[1][1] = 1;
  obstacles[2][0] = 0;
  obstacles[2][1] = 2;
  obstacles[3][0] = 0;
  obstacles[3][1] = 3;
  obstacles[4][0] = 4;
  obstacles[4][1] = 4;
  obstacles[5][0] = 4;
  obstacles[5][1] = 5;
  obstacles[6][0] = 4;
  obstacles[6][1] = 6;
  obstacles[7][0] = 4;
  obstacles[7][1] = 7;
  obstacles[8][0] = 0;
  obstacles[8][1] = 8;
  obstacles[9][0] = 0;
  obstacles[9][1] = 9;
  // etc. for every obstacle there is on your map
  // i did move some around just to demonstrate the principle, but yours are all in the same column
  
  // here I set up starting coordinates for the player character
  pcX = 6;
  pcY = 4;
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  drawBackground();
  drawPC();
}

void drawBackground() {
  int i;
  fill(200, 0, 0);
  
  // here I draw red squares on tiles that are obstacles. If your background isn't already drawn you don't have to do that part
  for (i=0; i<obstacles.length; i++) {
    rect(tileSize*obstacles[i][0], tileSize*obstacles[i][1], tileSize, tileSize);
  }
}

void move(int xx, int yy) {
  // if the player character cannot do that move, this method will return before the pc's coordinates are updated
  
  // validate if the player character is going to go out of the map (I made the map 10 tiles x 10 tiles)
  if (pcX + xx < 0 || pcX + xx > 9) { return; } 
  if (pcY + yy < 0 || pcY + yy > 9) { return; }
  
  // validate if the player character is going to walk over an obstacle
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<obstacles.length; i++) {
    if (pcX + xx == obstacles[i][0] && pcY + yy == obstacles[i][1]) { return; } 
  }
  
  // as there was nothing forbidding the move, the pc's coordinates can now be updated
  pcX += xx;
  pcY += yy;
}

void drawPC() {
  fill(0, 200, 0);
  rect(tileSize*pcX, tileSize*pcY, tileSize, tileSize);
}

void keyPressed() {
  println(pcY);
  if (key == 'd') { move(1,0); }
  if (key == 'a') { move(-1,0); }
  if (key == 's') { move(0,1); }
  if (key == 'w') { move(0,-1); }
}

Have fun!

Note that the OP has shown no work at all - just an idea / requirement. You wrote them a custom implementation - and this is not how Stack Overflow works.
